# Product of 64 digit numbers using Karatsuba algorithm

Tags: algorithm, karatsuba

How to use Karatsuba algorithm to calculate product of two 64 digit numbers such that only single digit numbers take part in multiplication ?

Comment: I am voting to close this question, because it's too broad...you need to be more specific, like, what have you tried, the programming language that you are using, you environment, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This StackExchange site is focused on programming. Your question would be more on topic on the Mathematics site or MathOverflow.

Comment: The Karatsuba algorithm lets you multiply N-digit numbers using 2N-digit addition and N/2-digit multiplication.  You will need to write a function for 128-digit addition, and your multiplication function should call itself recursively to do the smaller multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you posted this after going through Tim Roughgarden's course. What he actually meant was that you should multiply only a single digit to another single digit at a time, rather than use the computer to multiply multiple digits for you. In other words, multiply as if a human does it.